# Calculating a normal vector field for a surface defined by spherical harmonics

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces, vector-fields, spherical-harmonics

Given a surface defined by spherical harmonic terms

$f(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^lf_l^mY_l^m(\theta,\phi)$

How can I evaluate the normal vector at each location on the surface? i.e.
$\mathbf{N}(\theta,\phi)=N_r(\theta,\phi)\hat{\mathbf{r}}+N_\theta(\theta,\phi)\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}+N_\phi(\theta,\phi)\hat{\mathbf{\phi}}$

I imagine this answer lies somewhere in the vector spherical harmonics.. it feels like it should be true that the vector field produced by converting our scalar harmonics to vector terms as follows (using the notation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics) would produce the desired normal field but I have no idea how to verify this. Or how one would go about taking the gradient of spherical harmonics.

$\mathbf{Y}_{lm}=Y_{lm}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$

$\mathbf{\Psi}_{lm}=r\nabla Y_{lm}$

$\mathbf{\Phi}_{lm}=r\times\nabla Y_{lm}$

Comment: Why do you say normal vector"s"? Isn't there just one on your parametric surface $f(\theta,\phi)$?

Comment: I originally said vectors referring to the whole field but I guess that is a bit confusing, I fixed the wording. There should be one vector at each point along the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the derivative of $f$ along $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. Now take the cross product of \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} 
\end{pmatrix}=N
\end{equation}
Normalize and you are done.

Comment: By $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$ I assume you mean $\frac{\partial f}{sin(\theta)\partial\phi}$. But that does seem to answer the basics of the question, thanks! Now I just need to figure out how to take the gradient of the spherical harmonics properly.

Comment: Are the spherical harmonics of a particular form?

Comment: Yes, they are generated by the normalized associated legendre polynomials $\hat{P_l^m}(cos(\theta))$ as follows $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)=\hat{P_l^m}(cos(\theta))e^{im\phi}$. I think I've figured out how to take the gradient by using this reference Wang, B., Wang, LL. & Xie, Z. Adv Comput Math (2017). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10444-017-9569-1.  But my answer using the above method is still just so slightly off

Comment: You just need to apply the chain rule